# urllib.request.Request says arguments are invalid

Tags: python, twitter-oauth

I am getting the following error: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected bytes, bytearray, or an object with the buffer interface, tuple found`

I've checked the Python documentation, and the arguments for urllib.request.Request seem to be of the right type. What types are required for a POST request in urllib?

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import base64

class TweetGrabber:
    def __init__(self, key, secret):
        myKey = urllib.parse.quote_plus(key)
        mySecret = urllib.parse.quote_plus(secret)
        bearerTokenCredentials = myKey + ":" + mySecret
        bearerTokenCredentials = bytes(bearerTokenCredentials, "utf-8")
        bearerTokenCredentials = base64.b64encode(bearerTokenCredentials)
        url = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token'
        userAgent = "Tau v0.1"
        authorization = "Basic %s", bearerTokenCredentials
        contentLength = 29
        acceptEncoding = "gzip"
        contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
        values = {'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'}
        headers = {'User-Agent' : userAgent, 'Authorization' : authorization, 'Content-Type' : contentType, 'Content-Length' : contentLength, 'Accept-Encoding' : acceptEncoding}
        data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
        print(response.read())
```

Edit: entire error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TweetGrabber.py", line 27, in <module>
    x = TweetGrabber("key", "secret")
  File "TweetGrabber.py", line 24, in __init__
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 455, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 473, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 433, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1217, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1174, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
  File "C:\python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1090, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1123, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "C:\python34\lib\http\client.py", line 1069, in putheader
    value = b'\r\n\t'.join(values)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected bytes, bytearray, or an object with the buf
fer interface, tuple found
```

Comment: Post the whole trace back message.

Comment: What happens when you assign it to 2 values?  Like `response, code = urllib.request.urlopen(req)`.   I forget the order of them, but this may be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
authorization = "Basic %s", bearerTokenCredentials
```

This line is the error. `authorization` becomes a tuple and not a string. Easy fix:

```
authorization = "Basic %s" % bearerTokenCredentials
```